# I want to draw visio diagrams using IronPython

Tags: python, visio, shapes

For now i have this. I would like to add this new connector to my stencil and use it. Also how can i check what properties are required for the connector (like BeginX or EndY)

```
masterconnector = stencildoc.Masters.ItemU["dynamic connector"]

connector1 = page.Drop( masterconnector, -1,-1)
connector1.CellsU( "BeginX" ).GlueTo(shapeFrom.CellsSRC(1, 1, 0)) 
connector1.CellsU( "EndY" ).GlueTo(shapeTo.CellsSRC(1, 1, 0))
```

But i would like to use a directed connector. how do i do that.

Comment: Isn't a directed line just a style? So you should look under setting the line type?

Comment: The dynamic connector is directed as you see by it's fields BeginX, EndY, ...
If you need it with an arrow, so set the according property to it. (To find by recording a macro and formating the line according your needs).
HTH, Y. Yacine http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=4987.0

Answer (score 1):

for any one else who is looking to do this : Add this

```
connector1.cellsU("EndArrow").Formula = 1
```